# Choose a random letter and change it (JAVA)

Tags: java, string, random, replace, char

Hello everyone im new to Java and i need help in my code

```
/**
 * @(#)Changing.java
 *
 *
 * @author 
 * @version 1.00 2015/2/27
 */

import java.util.Random;

public class Changing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random generator = new Random();
        int num1;   
        String phrase = "This is a pencil";

        int len = phrase.length();
        num1 = generator.nextInt(len);
        char c = phrase.charAt(num1, 'x');
        String mut1 = phrase.replace(c, 'x');
        System.out.println(mut1);
    }
}
```

I need to make progrom to pick a random letter and change it to X

Thank you

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: @Jens -  this : `char c = phrase.charAt(num1, 'x');`  :P

Comment: As @TheLostMind pointed out, are you 100% sure of what the .charAt method does on a string?

Comment: Should be `char c = phrase.charAt(num1);`. But even so, wouldn't there be a chance of 1:4 or so that you get `mut1 = "This isXa pencil` ?

Comment: If a single char gets picked, then all occurences of that char (either letter or space) would be X. For example: when space gets picked, it will be `ThisXisXaXpencil` or "i" `Thxs xs a pencxl`.

Comment: @Nfear i don't think all spaces get replaced as there is only one index used at num1. Solution would be to check first if the charAt isn't a space, if so pick a new random number and check again.

Comment: @WonderWorld The char at the index is selected. Then that character is being replaced which includes all occurrences. The replace method states: `Returns a new string resulting from replacing all occurrences of oldChar in this string with newChar.`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `char c = phrase.charAt(num1, 'x');` to `char c = phrase.charAt(num1);`

There is no charAt method that takes two parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Nfear is correct with removing the 'x' from

```
char c = phrase.charAt(num1, 'x');
```

You may also want to consider an if statement to ensure you don't end up with
"Thisxisxaxpencil" as an answer. Unless of course you are ok with that output. See code below....

```
import java.util.Random;
public class Changing {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random generator = new Random();
    int num1;   
    String phrase = "This is a pencil";

    int len = phrase.length();
    char c = ' ';
    while(c == ' '){
        num1 = generator.nextInt(len);
        c = phrase.charAt(num1);
    }
    String mut1 = phrase.replace(c, 'x');
    System.out.println(mut1);

}
```

*edit*
You may also want to consider creating a char array instead of using .replace()

This will make it so you don't replace every 's' or every 'i' in your string. 
See code below...

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random generator = new Random();
    int num1 = 0;   
    String phrase = "This is a pencil";

    int len = phrase.length();
    char c = ' ';
    while(c == ' '){//to ensure we don't x out a space
        num1 = generator.nextInt(len);
        c = phrase.charAt(num1);
    }
    char[] phraseArray = phrase.toCharArray();//make string into a char[]
    phraseArray[num1] = 'x';//replace char the random char index with 'x' This replaces the random letter for you.
    String mut1 = new String(phraseArray);//change your char[]  back into a string
    System.out.println(mut1);//print results
}
```

Comment: this would still replace all `i`'s with an X. which is not what should happen.

Comment: Or use `String sub1 = phrase.substring(0, num1) + 'X' + phrase.substring(num1+1);` if you dont want to use a charArray.

Answer (score 0):

After looking around and dealing with several problems, i found that `StringBuilder()` does exactly what you are looking for.

```
    Random generator = new Random();
    int num1 = 0;
    StringBuilder phrase = new StringBuilder("This is a pencil");
    int len = phrase.length();
    char c = ' ';
    while (c == ' ') {
        num1 = generator.nextInt(len);
        c = phrase.charAt(num1);
    }
    phrase.setCharAt(num1, 'X');   // <-- i think this is a nice way to do it.
    //String sub1 = phrase.substring(0, num1) + 'X' + phrase.substring(num1+1); // Not so elegant as StringBuilder().
    System.out.println(phrase);
```